# How to use aggregation in Mongo db Java driver with $match and $in?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to convert below query into Java code for Mongo Java driver?

```
db.post.aggregate(
  [
    { $match : {"name" :{'$in': ["michael", "jordan"] } }},
    { $group : { _id : "$game.id" , count : { $sum : 1 } } }
    ]
)
```

My function is not working:

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject('$match', new BasicDBObject("name", names));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator takes and array or list of arguments, so any list will basically do. But you need to form the corresponding BSON. Indenting your code helps to visualize:

```
    BasicDBList inArgs = new BasicDBList();
    inArgs.add("michael");
    inArgs.add("jordan");

    DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",
        new BasicDBObject("name",
           new BasicDBObject("$in", inArgs )
        )
    );

    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group",
        new BasicDBObject("_id","$game.id").append(
            "count", new BasicDBObject("$sum",1)
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Aggregation Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/), your query should look like:

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject('$match', new BasicDBObject('name', new BasicDBObject('$in', names)));
```